# Connotation of "abazure" (shameless woman)?

Tags: word-choice, words, connotation

Kimetsu no Yaiba is an anime set during the Taishou era (early 1900s). During Katanakaji no Sato-hen (ep10), a man says to an overly-friendly-looking woman "だまれ、あばずれが", which is localized as "Shut up, you shameless tramp!" Also, jisho.org ( https://jisho.org/search/abazure ) also translates あばずれ as "bitch; shameless woman".

Anyways, my question is, what is the connotation of the expression? Is it a much more antiquated expression, or does it see any modern use? And meaning/intent-wise, is it basically the same as saying "破廉恥な女"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

あばずれ mostly corresponds to the English *bitch*, except that it is rarely used in modern Japanese speech.

The use in anime/manga is literary. I won't be surprised if あばずれ is used in a modern novel, but don't expect to hear it in real conversations. If it is ever used, the speaker would be a very old man with an outdated mindset (this is stereotyping).

あばずれ sounds to me more about promiscuity while 破廉恥な女 could mean a broader(?) shamelessness (such as wearing a dress exposing too much skin, speaking too explicitly in sexual matters etc).